# While typing, the cursor automatically shifts to the left in vscode

Tags: keyboard, visual-studio-code

While I am typing in the editor and the pointer(the straight line that blinks which shows where the "point" is) shifts to the left. I've tried and this doesn't happen anywhere else. I've tested the keyboard in Atom and Sublime.

Here is a .gif showing this:

[image: gif showing cursor shifting to left]

This happens even when all the extensions are disabled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was caused by setting the Auto Save to "After Delay" and keeping the "AutoSave Delay" to 1. If you change the delay to 200, it will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently if you have a file big enough and save it every one millisecond, this is bound to happen.

Comment: Yeah It was stupid of me to do that.